# R - Remove rows from dataframe that contain only zeros in numeric columns, base R and pipe-friendly methods?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'd like to remove all rows that sum to 0, but I have factor columns in the first 2 columns. I've come up with a dplyr solution, creating an intermediate rowsum column, filtering out rows that sum to 0, then removing that rowsum column.

I'd like to find a way for this to work without creating that unnecessary rowsum column, both using base R and a dplyr/tidyverse pipe-friendly method. Surely there's an easy, one-line piece of code to make this happen?

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(person = rep(c("Ed", "Sue"), 6),
                id = paste0("plot",1:12),
                a = c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0),
                b = c(0, 0, 6, 4, 0, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1),
                c = c(4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8),
                d = c(0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 9, 0, 1, 5),
                e = c(7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0))


##create intermediate 'row.sum' column, filter rows that have all 0's, then remove row.sum column
df1 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(row.sum = a+b+c+d+e) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(row.sum != 0) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-row.sum)


#end result:
#  person     id a b c d e
#1     Ed  plot1 2 0 4 0 7
#2     Ed  plot3 0 6 0 0 5
#3    Sue  plot4 0 4 0 3 0
#4    Sue  plot6 1 8 0 1 1
#5     Ed  plot7 0 1 0 0 0
#6     Ed  plot9 4 0 0 9 0
#7     Ed plot11 0 1 3 1 7
#8    Sue plot12 0 1 8 5 0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**A dplyr method**

You can apply rowSums to numeric columns only, using dplyrs `filter()` and `across()`, with the helper `where(is.numeric)`:

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%filter(rowSums(across(where(is.numeric)))!=0)

  person     id a b c d e
1     Ed  plot1 2 0 4 0 7
2     Ed  plot3 0 6 0 0 5
3    Sue  plot4 0 4 0 3 0
4    Sue  plot6 1 8 0 1 1
5     Ed  plot7 0 1 0 0 0
6     Ed  plot9 4 0 0 9 0
7     Ed plot11 0 1 3 1 7
8    Sue plot12 0 1 8 5 0
```

This method (and some of those that depend on `rowSums()`) can fail if your numeric columns have negative values as well.
In that case we must make sure that we keep only the rows that contain at least `any()`non-zero values. This can be done by modifying the `rowSums()` to include the condition `.x!=0`inside `across()`:

```
df%>%filter(rowSums(across(where(is.numeric), ~.x!=0))>0)
```

Or with logical operators and `Reduce()/reduce()`, with the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df%>%filter(pmap_lgl(select(., where(is.numeric)), ~any(c(...)!=0)))

#or with purrr:reduce()#

df%>%filter(across(where(is.numeric), ~.x!=0)%>%reduce(`|`))
#or simply
df%>%filter(reduce(across(where(is.numeric), ~.x!=0), `|`))
```

**a base R method**

You can use base subsetting with `[`, with `sapply(f, is.numeric)` to create a logical index to select only numerical columns to feed to the inequality operator `!=`, then take the `rowSums()` of the final logical matrix that is created and select only rows in which the rowSums is >0:

```
df[rowSums(df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)]!=0)>0,]
```

**EDIT**

We can benefit from the coercion that comes from calling logical functions on numeric vectors. `as.logical()` will evaluate zeroes to FALSE and any non-zero numbers to TRUE. `x|x` and nested bang signs `!(!)` will do the same. This is consistent with the other solutions that compare elements to ZERO, and is therefore more consistent than the `rowSums`solution.

An example:

```
vector<-c(0,1,2,-1)
identical(as.logical(vector), vector|vector, vector!=0, !(!vector))

[1] TRUE
```

There are some neat ways to solve this with that in mind:

```
df%>%filter(reduce(across(where(is.numeric), as.logical), `|`))
#or simply
df%>%filter(reduce(across(where(is.numeric)), `|`))
#and with base R:
df[Reduce(`|`, df[sapply(df, is.numeric)]),]
```

**And the cleanest so far, with the new `if_any()`:**

```
df%>%filter(if_any(where(is.numeric)))
```

Comment: Well-done! It's a thorough explanation for these kind of questions for future references.

Comment: Thanks, dear @Anoushiravan R. I always learn a lot from your contributions too.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. It's a great pleasure for me and that's very kind of you. As a matter of fact we are all learning here from one another.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative without using `rowSums`

- just used `all` inside `rowwise` `filter` converting desired vals into logical testing `== 0` with `cur_data()`

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% rowwise() %>%
  filter(!all(cur_data()[-c(1:2)] == 0))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 7
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   person id         a     b     c     d     e
#>   <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Ed     plot1      2     0     4     0     7
#> 2 Ed     plot3      0     6     0     0     5
#> 3 Sue    plot4      0     4     0     3     0
#> 4 Sue    plot6      1     8     0     1     1
#> 5 Ed     plot7      0     1     0     0     0
#> 6 Ed     plot9      4     0     0     9     0
#> 7 Ed     plot11     0     1     3     1     7
#> 8 Sue    plot12     0     1     8     5     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
subset(df, rowSums(df[3:7]) != 0)
   person     id a b c d e
1      Ed  plot1 2 0 4 0 7
3      Ed  plot3 0 6 0 0 5
4     Sue  plot4 0 4 0 3 0
6     Sue  plot6 1 8 0 1 1
7      Ed  plot7 0 1 0 0 0
9      Ed  plot9 4 0 0 9 0
11     Ed plot11 0 1 3 1 7
12    Sue plot12 0 1 8 5 0
```

Comment: Should be able to dispense with `!= 0`, since 0 is FALSE in R. Would however need to coerce to logical.

Comment: You code might be optimal for the base R situtation. I also tested `!!rowSums(df[3:7])` and it succeeds. It might create confusion in hte minds of tidyversians, since `!! has different interpretation in the "rlang" syntax.

Comment: @IRTFM, indeed, but isn't the bang bang operator used while calling an already saved string object? Don't use rland much but isn't `!!` replaced by `{{...}}` now.

Comment: It may well be, but it still throws an error when I tried it just now inside `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of mixture of base logic and tidy syntax. It's admittedly a bit tortured to  get around the alternate syntax that is rlang.

```
df1 <- df %>% filter(!(!rowSums(`[`(.,,3:7))))
> df1
  person     id a b c d e
1     Ed  plot1 2 0 4 0 7
2     Ed  plot3 0 6 0 0 5
3    Sue  plot4 0 4 0 3 0
4    Sue  plot6 1 8 0 1 1
5     Ed  plot7 0 1 0 0 0
6     Ed  plot9 4 0 0 9 0
7     Ed plot11 0 1 3 1 7
8    Sue plot12 0 1 8 5 0
```

Need to separate the two exclamation points with a paren, because `!!` is a different operation in "rlang" which is the logical environment for `filter`. (And note that rwoSums does have an `na.rm` argument if there are possibly NA's and those should be ignored.

And here's a base solution. Was `!!` working as a substitute for `!= 0`

```
df1 <- df[ as.logical(rowSums(df[3:7]) ), ]
```

(I think it's probably better to stick with `!= 0`)

Comment: I liked this `!(!` approach, but wonder whether just `as.logical` would not do just the same, but with superior readability

Comment: After thinking about it, I'm of the opinion that `!= 0` is probably clearly. I would still need to have `!as.logical(.)` and that seems almost as tortured.

Comment: I was actually thinking of something like `df %>% filter(as.logical(rowSums(`[`(.,,3:7))))`

Comment: See my updated answer to see what I mean. Thanks for the discussion, @IRTFM

Comment: Deleted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

We could calculate the row sums row wise and use `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  slice(unique(c(which(sum(c_across(where(is.numeric))) != 0))))
```

Output:

```
  person id         a     b     c     d     e
  <chr>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Ed     plot1      2     0     4     0     7
2 Ed     plot3      0     6     0     0     5
3 Sue    plot4      0     4     0     3     0
4 Sue    plot6      1     8     0     1     1
5 Ed     plot7      0     1     0     0     0
6 Ed     plot9      4     0     0     9     0
7 Ed     plot11     0     1     3     1     7
8 Sue    plot12     0     1     8     5     0
```