# r remove rows from data frame with greater than n zero values

Tags: r

I am working in R and I have a large dataframe with many rows and columns. The following data frame `df` is a minimal example.

```
#Example dataframe
row1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,0,8)
row2 <- c(1,0,0,0,10,0,0,0)
row3 <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0)

df <- t(data.frame(str1,str2,str3))
```

I would like to remove rows with >4 zero values yielding the following desired output.  However this has to be done in a high throughput manner.

```
#Desired Output
desired_output <- df[c(1,3),]
```

It seems that i need to do two things.

1. For each row count the number of columns containing a zero and return this information inside a loop or apply function.
2. use this information to subset the broader dataset.

Here is a non-functioning attempt

```
outlist <- list()

for (x in 1:length(rownames(df))) {
  out <- sapply(df[x,], function(x){sum(x>0)})
  print(out)
  append(outlist, out)
  }
```

Comment: How about `df[!rowSums(df == 0) > 4, ]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R - Remove rows from dataframe that contain only zeros in numeric columns, base R and pipe-friendly methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67754119/r-remove-rows-from-dataframe-that-contain-only-zeros-in-numeric-columns-base)
You can modify the answers here to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% filter(rowSums(across(everything(), ~.x==0))<=4)
```